# Merge Slick.js with FancyBox

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, slick.js

I have code for carousel like this:

```
$("#detail").slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 5000,
    arrows: false,
    speed: 500,
    infinite: true,
    pauseOnHover: true,
    dots: true
});
```

And on every slide, there is a icon for maximize with fancybox:

```
$('.preview').fancybox({
    'transitionIn': 'elastic',
    'transitionOut': 'elastic',
    'speedIn': 600,
    'speedOut': 200,
    'overlayShow': true,
    'cyclic': true
});
```

It works great, as I expected. When you click on the maximize icon on the first slide, it maximize and when you use arrows on the keyboard, it reacts for both slick and fancybox. But that's probably because both plugins use same bind for "next slide". So, this is not working, when you use mouse clicks instead of keyboard arrows. **Is it possible to merge their reacts together?** It doesn't relly matter, but when it is possible, it would be great.

Comment: @madalinivascu react/reacting - (i.e.) you press right arrow and it do something... I'm not sure now, if I use this word right way

Comment: trigger a click event for the fancybox arrow navigation when you click on the arrow navigation of the slick slider

Comment: But note that in question, slick.js has autoplay, so when it is maximized, it autoruns in the background and when it move by 3 slides on carousel and you click next on the fancybox, it will move to slide 4 on carousel and slide 2 on fancy box. That's why I'm asking, if someone know how to merge them, but when it is too complicated it doesn't matter.

Comment: It is quite easy to combine fancyBox3 with Slick, just set selector like this: `$().fancybox({ selector : '.slick-slide:not(.slick-cloned)' });`. See this example - https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/pdbrjx

Comment: @Janis this is little old question and I'm not using slick anymore, but thanks anyway.